# Dell Latitude D830 unable to connect to the internet

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

My Dell Latitude D830 (BCM4311 wireless chip) is unable to connect to any wireless connections or even detect them. I was able to find a driver for it but I don't know what to do with it. The driver is a .tar.gz file.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet and do:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Even with the wired connection, it doesn't seem like it is able to connect.